# How to add custom code for TouchUpInside event of button on non-start ViewController of storyboards?

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

I created story board application in XCode 4.3.3. (Single View Application -> Use storyboards checkbox)

Then I created second ViewController (first one is created when application initially created)

I added Round Rect Button with title "log2" to second ViewController.

Then I want to add code for handling event "TouchUpInside". To achive this I press Show the Assistant Editor" button and try to control drag "log2" button to source code of ViewController.h.
But nothing happens.

How to add TouchUpInside handler for "log2" button described above?

What is interesting, if I add button to the first ViewController, control-drag works fine for the button and I can create event handing.

Comment: Is ViewController.h the first view controller or the second?

Comment: It was created for first view controller. But there is no separate source files created for second ViewController. It seems they should be created in some way? I am just very new for XCode

Comment: Yes, you want to add a file, that's a subclass of UIViewController to your project, and set the second view controller in your storyboard to that class.  Then you should connect the button to that controller, not the first one.

Comment: Should I created manually class ViewController2 derived from UIViewController? This means that I should select File -> New -> File -> Objective-C class?

Comment: Yes. Then in the identity inspector you change the class of the view controller you added from UIViewController to whatever your new class is.

Comment: I caught it! Thanks, your comments are accepted answer for me :)

Comment: Thanks, I'll post my comments as an answer so you can accept it.

Comment: Sure, hope somebody else will find it useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you want to manually add a file, that's a subclass of UIViewController to your project, and set the second view controller in your storyboard to that class (in the identity inspector). Then you should connect the button to that controller, not the first one.